# Switch to existing open tab in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to VSCode and don't understand the default tab functionality. If I have a class in the right split panel and select the same class from the package selection menu it opens a second copy of the class in preview or edit in the left split menu. How can I change this behavior so that it switches to the selected class regardless of which panel it's in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure "workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true in settings to always reveal a file if already opened in any other group.

Comment: Was about to submit my own question on the same matter and saw your answer. Many thanks, "reveal if open" is far from search terms I used in VSCode settings